# Update Menu Item from a Fragment

Tags: android

I have an Activity which hosts a `ViewPager` of Fragments as pages.

The Activity has a single `MenuItem` which has to be enabled/disabled depending on the Actions in Fragments.

I could have gone with **Callbacks**, but is there a way to get the `MenuItem` of the parent Activity in the Fragment?

**like:** `getActvity().getActionBar().getMenuItem(0);`

Comment: `getActvity().getActionBar()` should be enough to get the Actionbar instance for the parent activity.

Comment: @Pete Yeah but I need the MenuItem, not just the ActionBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting docs

If you want to update

> Your fragments can contribute menu items to the activity's Options
>   Menu (and, consequently, the Action Bar) by implementing
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(). In order for this method to receive calls,
>   however, you must call setHasOptionsMenu() during onCreate(), to
>   indicate that the fragment would like to add items to the Options Menu
>   (otherwise, the fragment will not receive a call to
>   onCreateOptionsMenu()).

So have this in onCreate

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
// TODO Add your menu entries here
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in Fragment?